# App inventor replace background image with color

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am currently using MIT AppInventor to build an app

In the app, I wish to swap the background image with a colour during runtime using blocks. Is this possible or do I have to make a new blank image with a background colour?

I would make a blank image right away but I am hesitating to do so because the app is quite heavy with >20 images, 3 screens and hundreds of blocks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php) . *This should be easily doable. You might want to **edit** your question and show us, what you have tried.*

Comment: concerning the images, follow these tips: [Using Images with App Inventor](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/usingImages.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um.. Awkward moment here, but I found an answer

So I'll just keep this page for reference.

Setting background image to " " does the job. Without showing any error.

*facepalm*